# Confuse about the scope inherit between directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am wondering how to implement the scope inherit between directives.

For example:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>TEST DRAG</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="main">

    <dragcont>
        <dragitem></dragitem>
    </dragcont>



    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(){

            var app = angular.module("app", []);

            app.controller("main", function($scope){
                $scope.name = "Hello";
            })
            .directive("dragcont", function(){
                return {
                    restrict: "AE",
                    scope: {

                    },
                    controller: function($scope){
                        $scope.name = "dragcont";
                    },
                    link: function(scope, EL, attrs){

                    }
                }
            })
            .directive("dragitem", function(){
                return {
                    restrict: "AE",
                    controller: function($scope){
                        console.log($scope.name);
                    },
                    link: function(scope, EL, attrs){

                    }
                }
            })


        })()

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, it always prints Hello. It seems that dragitem can inherit the scope from main controller, but what if I want it to inherit from dragcont?

Comment: The child elements of the directive-hosting element do not inherit from an isolate scope of a directive. For your scenario to work, you either need to add `dragitem` inside a template of `dragcont` or manually transclude and link against the isolate scope. Isolate scope was meant to be used only by the author of the directive; and it is "isolated" from every one else

Comment: @NewDev Thanks,  this is funny. I tried the first way(put it in template). Could you give me an example of the second way(transclude and link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate scope is used to "isolate" the inner workings of a directive from its usage. As such, the scope neither inherits from its parent, nor can be inherited from by the child directives and expressions.

So, for the isolate `foo` directive:

```
.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope){
      scope.inner = "hidden from outside";
    }
  }
})
```

the child directives and expression will not inherit its isolate scope.

```
<foo>
  <span>{{inner}} will be undefined</span>
</foo>
```

**Using a `template`:**

On the other hand, a `template` of a directive `foo` is known to the author of the directive, and so it does use the isolate scope. The following would have worked, if `foo` had a template:

```
scope: {},
template: '<span>{{inner}}</span>',
link: function(scope){
   scope.inner = "hidden from outside";
}
```

**Using manual "transclusion":**

Occasionally, it makes sense to allow the user of the directive to specify a custom template. The author of the directive may also want to expose special "magic" variables to use in the custom template, not unlike `$index`, `$first`, etc.. of `ng-repeat`.

This can be done with a manual transclusion:

```
scope: {},
transclude: true,
template: '<div>{{header}}</div>\
           <placeholder></placeholder>',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
  scope.header = "I am foo"; // still only visible in the template

  // create a new scope, that inherits from parent, but a child of isolate scope
  var anotherScope = scope.$parent.$new(false, scope);
  anotherScope.$magic = "magic";

  // transclude/link against anotherScope
  transclude(anotherScope, function(clonedContents){
    element.find("placeholder").replaceWith(clonedContents);
  }
}
```

Now, you can have access to `$magic` variable inside the transcluded contents and to the outer scope (assuming it has `$scope.name = "John"`)

```
<foo>
  <div>I can see {{name}} and {{$magic}}</div>
</foo>
```

The resulting DOM will be:

```
<foo>
  <div>I am foo</div>
  <div>I can see John and magic</div>
</foo>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are still missing some work to be able to make a directive inherit from another.

I think this code will help you:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaPNqp?editors=101

Also, you might want to read:

http://david-barreto.com/directive-inheritance-in-angularjs/

### CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.data1 = "1";
  $scope.data2 = "2";
})​var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.data1 = "1";
  $scope.data2 = "2";
})
.directive('myWrapper', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    , transclude: true
    , scope: true
    , template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1><ng-transclude></ng-    transclude><h2>Finished wrapping</h2>'
    , controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
      $scope.title = $attrs.title;
      $scope.passdown = $attrs.passdown;
    }
  };
})
.directive('myInner1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    , require: 'myWrapper'
    , template: 'The data passed down to me is {{ passdown }}'
  };
})
.directive('myInner2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    , require: 'myWrapper'
    , template: 'The data passed down to me is {{ passdown }}'
  };
});
.directive('myWrapper', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    , transclude: true
    , scope: true
    , template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1><ng-transclude></ng-    transclude><h2>Finished wrapping</h2>'
    , controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
      $scope.title = $attrs.title;
      $scope.passdown = $attrs.passdown;
    }
  };
})
.directive('myInner1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    , require: 'myWrapper'
    , template: 'The data passed down to me is {{ passdown }}'
  };
})
.directive('myInner2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    , require: 'myWrapper'
    , template: 'The data passed down to me is {{ passdown }}'
  };
});
```

which is found very useful. Make sure you read the comments below the article as well.

Pay attention to the "require" property.

Regards.